# Netsuite Suitescript 2 - Customer Deposit remaining amount in Search

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm facing a problem while performing a custom search on customer deposits in NetSuite using SuiteScript 2.0

I need to fetch all the customer deposits ids, statuses, the amount deposited and the amount remaining (I mean the amount that has not been applied to any invoice). My problem is that I can't figure out how to grab the amount remaining.

I have tried this:

```
var results = [];

search.create({           
    type: search.Type.CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT,
    filters: [['lastmodifieddate', 'within', context.from_datetime, context.to_datetime]],
    columns: [
        'entity',
        'status',
        'amount',
        'amountremaining'
    ]
}).run().forEach(function() {
    results.push(result);
    return true;
});

return results;
```

But `amountremaining` field comes empty for all the deposits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `applyingtransaction` field joined, I managed to get what I wanted with this code:

```
var results = [];

search.create({           
    type: search.Type.CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT,
    filters: [['lastmodifieddate', 'within', context.from_datetime, context.to_datetime]],
    columns: [
        'entity',
        'status',
        'amount',
        search.createColumn({
            name: "total",
            join: "applyingtransaction"
        })
    ]
}).run().forEach(function(result) {

    var appliedValue = parseFloat(result.getValue({ name: 'total', join: 'applyingtransaction' }));

    if (result.id in results) {
        results[result.id].remaining_credit += appliedValue;
    } else {
        var total = parseFloat(result.getValue('total'));

        results[result.id] = {
            remaining_credit: parseFloat(total + appliedValue),
        }
    }
});

return results;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `amountremaining` column isn't related to Customer Deposits, but you can achieve what you need by using the following approach.

First you need to add a filter to ensure you pull the correct 'applying transactions':

```
["applyingtransaction.type","anyof","DepAppl"]
```

This makes sure you get 'Deposit Applications' but not 'Deposits' which may be applying transactions of the Customer Deposit.  Then you need to add a column with a formula to add the amounts from all those Deposit Applications to the total amount of the Customer Deposit:

```
search.createColumn({
     name: "formulacurrency",
     summary: "MIN",
     formula: "min({amount}) + SUM({applyingtransaction.amount})",
     label: "Formula (Currency)"
  })
```

Note that this is *added* rather than subtracted, because the `applyingtransaction.amount` is returned as a negative.

Also not that this requires a summary column in order to work (as there may be more than one applying transaction per customer deposit), therefore you will need to apply a grouping or summary function to all the columns you need to return.  Most importantly, you need to GROUP by the customer deposit internal id or document number.